# Pandas: how to group-by a symbol and take the mean every n rows

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Suppose I have the following data frame *df*:

```
        date        symbol_a  symbol_b   ratio  
    0    2017/01/01    AAAA       AA       10
    1    2017/01/02    AAAA       AA       20
    2    2017/01/03    AAAA       AA       30
    3    2017/01/04    AAAA       AA       10
    4    2017/01/05    AAAA       AA       10 
    5    2017/01/06    AAAA       AA       10
    6    2017/01/01    BBBB       BB       10
    7    2017/01/02    BBBB       BB       20
    8    2017/01/03    BBBB       BB       30
    9    2017/01/04    BBBB       BB       10
   10    2017/01/01    CCCC       CC       10
   11    2017/01/02    CCCC       CC       20
   12    2017/01/03    CCCC       CC       30
   13    2017/01/04    CCCC       CC       10
   14    2017/01/05    CCCC       CC       10  
   15    2017/01/06    CCCC       CC        5
```

I am interested in mean values of the *ratio* column (this comes from the previous data frame that had two additional columns value_a value_b and ratio = value_a/value_b, more or less). What I would like to do is the following:

to take the mean values by symbol_a (or _b actually is the same) every n elements. Let's say n=3.

Ordinarely I would do something like:

```
df.groupby(['symbol_a','symbol_b']).mean()
```

However, I would like to get sub-means every 3 days (the actual time span obviously is much longer and I would need it every 5).

Initially I thought I would have always the same number of symbols, divisible by *n*, and so I tried something like:

```
df.groupby([df.index/n, 'symbol_a', 'symbol_b']).mean().reset_index()
```

This was quite working but strongly relied on the assumption of divisibility by *n*. Unfortunately not only that is an assumption I'd like to drop, but I also noticed that not all the symbols come out *n* times: notice for example that symbol_a "BBBB" only appear four times (days). This of course makes the above attempt completely unreliable as it will mix ratio values of different symbols.

To recap, I would need something that let me have the mean of the *ratio* column every n elements, and if the number of symbols is not divisible by n, it gets the mean every *n* and in the end the mean of the reminder (if number_of_symbols < n just the mean on such number).

For example the result would look something like (supposing n=3):

```
      symbol_a  symbol_b   3_mean_ratio
0       AAAA       AA          20       
1       AAAA       AA          10
2       BBBB       BB          20   
4       BBBB       BB          10   
5       CCCC       CC          20       
6       CCCC       CC         8.33
```

Is there any way to do something like this? Any help is very appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers so far. One last thing that would be ideal is an easy way to put the new *n-days-ratio* column next to the original one. Of course the length of this new one is shorter but I would not mind if the elements are repeated. Basically I need a way to select "good rows" based on this average. So far I'm creating a dictionary as a middle step but I'm sure there is a better way. If I could obtain something like below would be great:

```
        date        symbol_a  symbol_b   ratio  n-days-ratio
    0    2017/01/01    AAAA       AA       10      20
    1    2017/01/02    AAAA       AA       20      20
    2    2017/01/03    AAAA       AA       30      20
    3    2017/01/04    AAAA       AA       10      10
    4    2017/01/05    AAAA       AA       10      10
    5    2017/01/06    AAAA       AA       10      10
    6    2017/01/01    BBBB       BB       10      20
    7    2017/01/02    BBBB       BB       20      20
    8    2017/01/03    BBBB       BB       30      20
    9    2017/01/04    BBBB       BB       10      10
   10    2017/01/01    CCCC       CC       10      20
   11    2017/01/02    CCCC       CC       20      20
   12    2017/01/03    CCCC       CC       30      20
   13    2017/01/04    CCCC       CC       10     8.3
   14    2017/01/05    CCCC       CC       10     8.3
   15    2017/01/06    CCCC       CC        5     8.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edit adding n-days average column

```
g = df.groupby('symbol_a').cumcount()
df['n-days-ratio'] = df.groupby(['symbol_a','symbol_b',g // 3]).transform(lambda x: x.mean())
df
```

Output:

```
          date symbol_a symbol_b  ratio  n-days-ratio
0   2017/01/01     AAAA       AA     10     20.000000
1   2017/01/02     AAAA       AA     20     20.000000
2   2017/01/03     AAAA       AA     30     20.000000
3   2017/01/04     AAAA       AA     10     10.000000
4   2017/01/05     AAAA       AA     10     10.000000
5   2017/01/06     AAAA       AA     10     10.000000
6   2017/01/01     BBBB       BB     10     20.000000
7   2017/01/02     BBBB       BB     20     20.000000
8   2017/01/03     BBBB       BB     30     20.000000
9   2017/01/04     BBBB       BB     10     10.000000
10  2017/01/01     CCCC       CC     10     20.000000
11  2017/01/02     CCCC       CC     20     20.000000
12  2017/01/03     CCCC       CC     30     20.000000
13  2017/01/04     CCCC       CC     10      8.333333
14  2017/01/05     CCCC       CC     10      8.333333
15  2017/01/06     CCCC       CC      5      8.333333
```

Let's use:

<strike>g = df.groupby('symbol_a')['ratio'].transform(lambda x:x.astype(bool).cumsum().add(-1))</strike>

Let's use piRSquare's `cumcount` approach instead.

```
g = df.groupby('symbol_a').cumcount()

df_out = df.groupby(['symbol_a','symbol_b',g // 3]).mean().reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  symbol_a symbol_b      ratio
0     AAAA       AA  20.000000
1     AAAA       AA  10.000000
2     BBBB       BB  20.000000
3     BBBB       BB  10.000000
4     CCCC       CC  20.000000
5     CCCC       CC   8.333333
```

Comment: This looks great. It would be awesome if you could elaborate a little more the answer. I suppose the integer division is what guarantees that elements will be grouped 3 by 3 and the reminder will be grouped as it is. Maybe I'm not sure I understand how you build g and why you reset the index twice in df_out. Thank you though, good answer.

Comment: @Tommy... sure. the way I build g was using basically counting the records in each group by using cumsum then subtracting -1 to get the integer division to workout for grouping every three records.  However, piRSquared has a better way of calculating g using cumcount.  We are doing the same thing just that his way is more elegant, I am going to change my g to his code.  And I, had to reset the index twice because one of my index name was already in column names therefore I had to reset and drop that index first then used reset_index get everything back into columns. See my edits.

Comment: Thanks for the edits and the explanations. It's clearer now and it seems to work well. Talking about elegance, is there an easy way to put the new n-days average column next to the original one? Let me edit a moment my question to make this clearer.

Comment: @Tommy Sure.  See the edits in the answer.  Use `transform` with lambda function to calc mean for that group.

Comment: Thanks! Seems it's working fine, really appreciate your help. I just started using pandas on a new project and I'm quite new to data frames in general. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Generate a new column to group by with `cumcount() // 3`

```
cols = ['symbol_a', 'symbol_b']
cc = df.groupby(cols).cumcount() // 3
cols += ['Cumcount']

d1 = df.assign(Cumcount=cc)

d1.groupby(cols).ratio.mean().reset_index('Cumcount', drop=True).reset_index()

  symbol_a symbol_b      ratio
0     AAAA       AA  20.000000
1     AAAA       AA  10.000000
2     BBBB       BB  20.000000
3     BBBB       BB  10.000000
4     CCCC       CC  20.000000
5     CCCC       CC   8.333333
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a very nice reply as @Scott Boston also pointed out. After all I decided to accept his answer because it came first and provided helpful comments. Thanks a lot for answering though, in cases like this I'd be happy to accept both if I could.